# Prove that $(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y})|f(z)|^2 = 4|f'(z)|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Knowing: $f(z)$ is analytical

Prove:
$$(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y})|f(z)|^2 = 4|f'(z)|^2$$

---

I have proved firstly that $\ln|f(z)|$ is **harmonic** function

Let $$f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$$

And I transformed what to prove into:
$$u(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y}) + v(\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 y}) = 0$$

However, when I was trying to use:
$$(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y})\ln|f(z)|=0$$
I came into trouble. This equation is too complex to expand.

So, I supposed that there should be a better idea. It is nice of you to give a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to rewrite the Laplacian in terms of complex (Wirtinger) derivatives, as in [Show that $4\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/932264/). The note that in a neighborhood of  a point where $|f|\ne 0$ you can write $$\ln |f| = \frac12\ln f+\frac12 \ln \bar f$$
which is the sum of holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions. Now it should be easy to apply the Laplacian in the above form.

---

Another approach is more real-variable based: for every smooth function $u$ on a domain in $\mathbb R^n$ we have 
$$\nabla e^{u} = e^u \nabla u$$
hence
$$\Delta e^u = \operatorname{div}\nabla e^u = \nabla e^u\cdot  \nabla u+e^u \operatorname{div}\nabla u = e^u |\nabla u|^2+e^u\Delta u$$
Apply this to $u=2\ln|f|$ which you know to be harmonic; conclude 
$$\Delta |f|^2 =  4 |f|^2 |\nabla \ln |f||^2 $$
Then it remains to check that $|\nabla \ln |f||^2 = |f'(z)|^2/|f(z)|^2$.

Comment: Thank a lot, but I found it confusing to apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}$ to $\ln{f(z)}$ or $\ln{f(\bar z)}$, mainly due to the conjugation sign. Would you be so nice to offer a more detailed illustration.